# Maintain bits when converting from UInt32 to Int32

Tags: vb.net, integer-overflow

I need to map coordinates (Row, Column), which are positive integer values.
I implement `.GetHashCode` in the following way:

```
    Public Function GetHashCode As Integer
            If _HashCode Is Nothing Then
                Const BitsPerValue As Integer = 32 \ 2
                Dim UnsignedCode As UInt32 = CType(Me.Row, UInt32) Xor (CType(Me.Column, UInt32) << BitsPerValue)
                _HashCode = CType(UnsignedCode, Int32)
            End If
            Return _HashCode.Value
    End Function
    Private _HashCode As Integer?
```

Note `Me.Row >= UInt16.MinValue And Me.Row <= UInt16.MaxValue` and same goes for `.Column`.

**Performance is key**. I do not mind what the HashCode is. I believe the optimal convertion from `UInt32` to `Int32` should not change the bits in memory. But I am bothered because this is probably what is happening, as both of the following lines return the same value:

```
    Dim Unsigned123 As UInt32 = 123
    Dim Unsigned456 As UInt32 = 456
    Console.WriteLine("(UInt32) 123 Xor (456 << 16) = " & CType(Unsigned123 Xor (Unsigned456 << 16), UInt32))
    Console.WriteLine("(Int32) 123 Xor (456 << 16) = " & CType(Unsigned123 Xor (Unsigned456 << 16), Int32))
```

How can I cast without changing the bits in memory? I understand the `unchecked()` expression in C# would be ideal here, but it's not available for VB.Net.

I could use `BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(UnsignedCode), 0)` but is that not a greedy operation?

This is basically the opposite question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210383/uint32-to-int32), where I would **want** 3392918397 to become -902048899

Comment: Nothing went wrong here, the question is focusing on the wrong problem.  You can't get a perfect hash, too many bits.  Trouble starts when Column >= 32768, try it.  Squeezing out an extra bit in the final value does require the StructLayout hack, or disabling overflow checking in the project properties.

Comment: Indeed.. I am not worried about the hashcode, but I have now understood the `<<` does not throw an overflow exception, only casting a type to another when the source value does not fit within the range of the destination type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected that casting two integers from one type to the other does return the same value (both bit-wise an base10 -wise), as soon as they do not overflow.

Consider the following:

```
    Dim SignedMin As Int32 = Int32.MinValue
    Dim SignedMax As Int32 = Int32.MaxValue
    Dim UnsignedMin As UInt32 = UInt32.MinValue
    Dim UnsignedMax As UInt32 = UInt32.MaxValue

    Console.WriteLine("SignedMin As UInt32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(SignedMin, UInt32)))) 'OverflowException
    Console.WriteLine("SignedMax As UInt32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(SignedMax, UInt32)))) 'FF-FF-FF-7F
    Console.WriteLine("UnsignedMin As UInt32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(UnsignedMin, UInt32)))) '00-00-00-00
    Console.WriteLine("UnsignedMax As UInt32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(UnsignedMax, UInt32)))) 'FF-FF-FF-7F

    Console.WriteLine("SignedMin As Int32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(SignedMin, Int32)))) '00-00-00-80
    Console.WriteLine("SignedMax As Int32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(SignedMax, Int32)))) 'FF-FF-FF-7F
    Console.WriteLine("UnsignedMin As Int32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(UnsignedMin, Int32)))) '00-00-00-00
    Console.WriteLine("UnsignedMax As Int32 = " & BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(UnsignedMax, Int32)))) 'OverflowException
```

Returns

```
SignedMin As UInt32 = OverflowException
SignedMax As UInt32 = FF-FF-FF-7F
UnsignedMin As UInt32 = 00-00-00-00
UnsignedMax As UInt32 = FF-FF-FF-FF

SignedMin As Int32 = 00-00-00-80
SignedMax As Int32 = FF-FF-FF-7F
UnsignedMin As Int32 = 00-00-00-00
UnsignedMax As Int32 = OverflowException
```

Bit shift operations `<<` and `>>` do overflow without throwing an exception. The overflown bits are lost.